# I install the Neo4j service. Which files are they exactly and where are they?

Tags: windows, service, neo4j

From [Windows installation - Operations Manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/windows/#windows-service):

> Neo4j can also be run as a Windows service. Install the service with `bin\neo4j install-service`, and start it with `bin\neo4j start`.

But where is the service installed? Googling with the query [`where is neo4j service installed`](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=where+is+neo4j+service+installed) doesn't give any meaningful result.

Answer (score 0):

This question is about installing Neo4j as windows service in Windows OS. What you missed is the first step in installing Neo4j.  In step 3 of topic 1 of Windows Installation, it says;

```
 Right-click the downloaded file, click Extract All.
```

So when you do that step, it will prompt you where you would want the installation will be.  It is not that clear where the location of the installation because you have to go thru the entire installation process to see it.

Comment: I wouldn't say unextracting files is installing. A typical installation requires at least an installer, which apparently doesn't apply in this case.

Comment: Did you found your answer? If yes, then the community is happier that you got the help you need. If you have another question, then we will be happier to answer your new SO question. Thanks.

Comment: No I didn't have the answer yet. I still don't know what that command does, and where is the location it's installed